# Sum of distinct element in a range

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree

Consider a array (0 based index) i have to find the sum of distinct
element of all possible range[i,n] where 0< i < n

#### Example:

```
arr={1,2,1,3}

sum_range[0,3]={1,2,3}=6
sum_range[1,3]={1,2,3}=6
sum_range[2,3]={1,3}=4
sum_range[3,3]={3}=3
```

O(n^2) solution is one possible solution and i have read persistent segment tree can also do this though i can't find good tutorial.

Can it be solved in less than O(N^2) time?

If someone points persistent segment tree please explain or provide some good link?

Comment: dasblinkenlight's algorithm is better, but another strategy would be to sort the part of the array that is within the range (`O(n log n)`), then traverse the sorted array while summing the elements that are different than their predecessors (`O(n)`), giving an overall time complexity of `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in O(n) with a simple dynamic programming algorithm.

Start from the back of the array, and use a hash-based container to store the numbers that you have already encountered. The value of the last element, i.e. `sum_range[n-1]` is set to `arr[n-1]`. After that, values of `sum_range[i]` should be computed as follows:

- If `arr[i]` is not in the set of seen numbers, `sum_range[i] = sum_range[i+1]+arr[i]`
- Otherwise, `sum_range[i] = sum_range[i+1]`

Since the cost of checking a hash container for a value is O(1) and the cost of adding an item to hash container is amortized O(1) for n items, the overall cost of this algorithm is O(n).

Compared to O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm that uses O(1) space, this algorithm uses additional O(n) space for the hash container.

Comment: Do you have a source for hash insert and lookup complexity ? I always heard this was O(log(n)) at best, because of collisions. I fail to find any source arguing for or against this.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek [Hash table : performance analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Performance_analysis)

Answer (score 0):

Slice the array (O(n)), then use a set and add values to the set.

In python3.x code, edited after a comment:

```py
array = [1, 2, 1, 3, 5]
range_sum = 0
total_sum = 0
valueset = set ()
for val in reversed(array):
    if val not in valueset :
        valueset.add (val)
        range_sum += val
    total_sum += range_sum

print (total_sum)
```

Comment: Where do you get a log n with set?

Comment: OP asks for "sum of distinct element of all possible range[i,n]". This doesn't answer that.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this.

1. sort the array by `Arrays.sort();`
2. Using set

   ```
   long sumOfDistinct(long arr[], int N)
   {
        int size = arr.length;
        HashSet<Long> unique = new HashSet<Long>(); 
        long sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
                if(!unique.contains(arr[i])){
                    sum = sum + arr[i];
                    unique.add(arr[i]);
                }
        }

        return sum;
    }
   ```